# Create symbolic link instead of coping the content to the output directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, symlink, solution

Let's assume I've a Visual Studio solution with 50 C# projects.

`Project 1` has a native DLL which gets loaded from `Project 1`.

All other projects depend on `Project 1`.

The native DLL has size of 200 MB and the `Copy to Output Directory` is set to `Copy if newer`.

When I build this solution, the content of `Project 1` is copied to the `bin\Debug` and `bin\Release` folders of all projects. So I'm having 100 copies of this native DLL which has size of 200 MB. So in total 20 GB.

How can I avoid that huge size of my solution directory? It would be nice if I could avoid coping the content of `Project 1` and use a symbolic link instead. But I found no way for it.

Comment: The `Build Action` is set to `Content` for the native DLL.

Comment: Could ReFS be a solution? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/block-cloning

Comment: `ReFS block cloning` seams not working, see https://superuser.com/questions/1762696/refs-block-cloning-use-command-line-to-copy-a-file-and-use-block-cloning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, if that suits your needs, but you can "instruct" MSBuild (does not work when building from/inside Visual Studio) to use hard links, instead of actual file copies.

There are a number of properties that influence the respective behaviour, when set to `true`:

- `CreateHardLinksForCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryIfPossible`
- `CreateHardLinksForCopyAdditionalFilesIfPossible`
- `CreateHardLinksForCopyLocalIfPossible`
- `CreateHardLinksForPublishFilesIfPossible`

Basically, they set the `UseHardlinksIfPossible` property of the `Copy`-task in given situations (so you could instruct your own Copy-Task usages with this as well).

Another option would be to use a common output directory for all projects. That, however, has its own set of implications (further info by searching for "UseCommonOutputDirectory").

Comment: Using `msbuild` from the command line and any or all of your properties doesn't solve the problem for my native DLL. The files under `_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory` are still copied.

Comment: Using the following command `msbuild Solution.sln -t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:CreateHardLinksForAdditionalFilesIfPossible=true` generates hard links for the native DLL. See as well https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#MSBuildFiles/C/ProgramFiles(x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin_/amd64/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets,4089

Answer (score 3):

To automatically apply the optimized settings to all projects, create a file named `Directory.Build.props` in the root of the solution with the following content:

```xml
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!--
        Use hard links to speed up build.
        NOTE: This means dependencies' files might be locked on execute as well, so re-building them while the application is running might fail.
        -->
        <CreateHardLinksForAdditionalFilesIfPossible>true</CreateHardLinksForAdditionalFilesIfPossible>
        <CreateHardLinksForCopyLocalIfPossible>true</CreateHardLinksForCopyLocalIfPossible>
        <CreateHardLinksForCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryIfPossible>true</CreateHardLinksForCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryIfPossible>
        <CreateHardLinksForPublishFilesIfPossible>true</CreateHardLinksForPublishFilesIfPossible>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

(The effect can be verified in a POSIX shell by running eg. `ls -la bin/Debug/net7.0` and looking at the number in the second column, which is the hardlink count and should be greater than 1. For Windows, using eg. [FindLinks by Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/findlinks))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with symbolic link. But you can see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/vslangproj.reference.copylocal?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#remarks):

> At run time, assemblies must be in one of two locations: the output path of the project or the global assembly cache.

You can use [Global Assembly Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/working-with-assemblies-and-the-gac?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and set Copy Local property to No in visual studio:
[image]

The bin\debug folder will be cleaner:
[image]